# I cannot create properly aliases

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to create aliases in my react project (CRA 3.1.1) but I do not manage to achieve it. I have tried several options and none of them works. I only managed to alias the simple "src" folder following some blogs. As far as I try to go on from there, it does not work.

My folder structure is as follows:

- client/index.js
- client/src/components
- client/src/components/App/App.js

In my index.js I would like to do:

```
import App from "App/App.js";
```

My jsconfig.json is as follows:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
  "target": "es2018",
  "checkJs": true,
  "baseUrl": "src"
},
"include" : ["src" , "src/components"],
"exclude": ["node_modules", "**/node_modules/*"]
}
```

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: did you add an alias in webpack.config.js?

Comment: Which module bundler are you using? webpack? parcel?

Comment: I am using webpack but I cannot change the configuration as I have not ejected my application. The error message is one like "Module not found: Can´t resolve "App/App.js"

Answer (score 0):

In your webpack config, inside you `resolve` object define `alias`. For example if you want to use `App` instead of giving full path `client/src/components/App` you can write something like:

```
...
resolve: {
  ...
  alias: {
    'App': 'client/src/components/App'
  }
  ...
}
...
```

You might need to run `yarn eject` on your CRA app if you don't see the webpack config.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to mention that; I have not ejected my application. There is no way to do this without ejecting? I have seen several ways but none of them worked :(

Comment: @JavierGuzman I don't think that would be possible. But there are other alternatives to ejecting CRA. You can read them here https://create-react-app.dev/docs/alternatives-to-ejecting